# Scraping through VIEWSTATE

Tags: c#, .net, screen-scraping, viewstate

I've come across an issue while I was writing a utility to scrape a web page.

I'm sending POST requests to retrieve data, I mimic the behavior of the web I'm scrapping (According to info collected with fiddler).

I've been able to automatically replace all params on my POST except VIEWSTATE.
my guess is that the web is performing some logic according to the given VIEWSTATE, and that's why I'm not getting the expected result (I tried entering the value fiddler gives inside VIEWSTATE and then I do get the expected results, however I want to automate this process)

Is there a way I can edit a VIEWSTATE string without damaging it?

I tried decoding & encoding back using base64 (and finally URLEncode before POST action), couldn't keep it valid.

Comment: .Net sites are too much of a pain to scrape without something like mechanize. I'm not sure what options exist for c# though.

Comment: @pguardiario I guess so. I think I might just take a different direction, maybe using Custom scripts made using Silenium. a bit less manually.

Comment: @AlonAmir, don't go with Selenium it's too much work. I had the same issue and this link was helpful: https://asoftwaredeveloper.wordpress.com/category/extracting-view-state/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The viewstate is probably encrypted.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx

The viewstate ***should*** be encrypted, anyway. It's a protection aganst XSRF attacks of the type you seem to be trying to do :-)

The bottom line is the ViewState you send back must be the same as the viewstate the server sent to you. That's pretty much what it is for. In other words, to do what you are trying to do you have to keep a copy of the viewstate the server sent you, and send the same viewstate back. The server will then send you a new viewstate, which you must submit with your next request, and so on.

Comment: keeping the VIEWSTATE means I have to perform each step of the form I'm scrapping. i thought I could maybe somehow skip some steps required to fill the form, because i already have the information that needs to be entered - all except VIEWSTATE. I guess I have no option to extract the VIEWSTATE as is and do it step by step as a user would do.

Comment: @AlonAmir, Correct. The purpose of encrypted viewstate is to force you to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I benefited this a lot in web scraping.

Comment: there is another problem when send viewstate, I only get page 1-10 and when send request for page 11, I get response of page one !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same serializator asp.net uses. I think it is a class named HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hiddenfieldpagestatepersister.aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: Would be nice if I could, I can't see how I can initialize an instance of that class from a view state string. looks like it can only be used when actually creating a .net web

Comment: Check the base class, maybe subclassing it will help. I guess it has a template method for getting and setting the string.